# Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin on APK build flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart

Got the following error when i upgraded to the latest version of flutter

Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its
metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

...

[!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.
│
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update /Users/mac/projects/mate/android/build.gradle: │
│ ext.kotlin_version = ''

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10' //changed version 1.8.0 but still din't work
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
}
```

}

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

Comment: It seems there is a dependency chain from Kotlin 1.8.0 > Gradle 8.0.2 > JDK17. And this warrants updates in the Manifest and build.gradle to migrate to supported syntax.